# toLowerCase() with `filter` in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

How to use `toLowerCase()` with `filter()` in jquery?

Here is the dropdown that I have:

```
<select id="drpParty" name="drpParty" data-placeholder="Choose Party...." required="" class="chzn-select span8 row-fluid">
   <option value="-1" selected="" disabled="">Chose Customer</option>
   <option value="1">Party Ahmed</option>
   <option value="2">Party Ahmed</option>
   <option value="3">Ukraine</option>
   <option value="5">America</option>
   <option value="6">Indonesia</option>
   <option value="8">wheere</option>
   <option value="9">new party</option>
   <option value="10">Nwe Pary</option>
   <option value="11">Latest party </option>
   <option value="12">sha</option>
   <option value="13">shaj</option>
   <option value="14">My new party without salesman info</option>
   <option value="15">testing the latest party with hierarchy</option>
   <option value="16">testing the value</option>
   <option value="17">Kamran Ahmed</option>
   <option value="18">Testing a new party</option>
   <option value="19">Sale</option>
</select>
```

And I want to fetch the option that has "Sale" as it's text. I am using the following and it works perfectly that the `option` is being found:

```
var lookup = 'Sale';
var elem=$('#drpParty option:contains('+ lookup +')').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === lookup;
});

console.log(elem.val());
```

Now the text `Sale` may not necessarily be in this case inside the drop down i.e. it may be all upper case or all lower case, so I am trying this i.e. making the text of the `option` lower case and then comparing it with the `lookup`:

```
var lookup = 'sale';
var elem=$('#drpParty option:contains('+ lookup +')').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase() === lookup;
});

console.log(elem.val());
```

But it doesn't work then i.e. the `option` is not fetched. What am I doing wrong with the comparison that it doesn't return this element in this case?

**Fiddle here** http://jsfiddle.net/7xK82/

Comment: Please be careful when you do this sort of comparison using toLowerCase() explicitly. It doesn't work in every language (first example that comes to my mind is Turkey) so if your web site must work with international customers.

Comment: @Adriano: once we start there things go a _long_ way downhill -- all sorts of edge cases come up when we start to try and support "international" characters, which people would expect to be supported as it's mostly implemented correctly.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I agree but IMO nowadays they're not such corner cases and in this case **toLocaleLowerCase()** would at least _minimize_ some of them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `:contains` jQuery selector is case sensitive, so you'd need to filter for it manually as you've already done. What you should do is just remove the `:contains` part of your selector, and just grab all the `<option>` and filter through them, for example:

```
var lookup = 'sale';
var elem = $('#drpParty > option').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase() === lookup.toLowerCase();
});
```

Note that for performance reasons, it's often better to explicitly specify in your selector that it's a child element by using `>` instead of just looking for any descendants of your `<select>` element.

Comment: If that's the case then IMO @Nico's answer would me more efficient, as instead of performing the filter over all the `option` elements, he is just perfoming the filter over those `option` elements that contain `Sale` somewhere in their text.

Comment: @KamranAhmed: If you look at the answer carefully, you'd see that's indeed not the case (though he does not say so explicitly) -- all descendants of the `<select>` element are being filtered.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `.find` with just a tag name is faster because it'll just use `getElementsByTagName`. Longer expressions become harder to parse for the Sizzle engine, and they might get off-handed to `querySelectorAll`

Comment: @Nico: true that ([jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-child-selector-vs-find/8)), it appears only classes, IDs and tag names are optimised for by the Sizzle engine.

Answer (score 3):

Just compare them insensitively

```
var lookup = 'Sale';
var insensitive = lookup.toLowerCase();
var elem=$('#drpParty').find('option').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase() === insensitive;
});

console.log(elem.val());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7xK82/4/

Answer (score 1):

You could make your own case insensitive `contains` filter

```
// to make :contains case insensitive!!!
$.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function (arg) {
    return function (elem) {
        return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});
```

After the above codes executes the `:contains` filter will become case insensitive and you can use it anywhere without any other care about character casing. Make sure it runs only after the jQuery is loaded and it needs to run only once.
It might break if / when jQuery changes it's internal functions and structure again.

Comment: would you please explaing your answer a bit.

Comment: Also you might find that unexpected behaviour occurs where other code expects it to be case sensitive -- it might not be a bad idea to rename your case-insensitive `:contains` to something else. Anyway, +1 for a creative solution :)